# Combining a list of things, two things at a time, trying every combination possible

Tags: java, math

I am not sure how to explain this very well, so please edit and ask if need be. I think this might have a math driven solution. I am trying to find all the ways items can be combined together in order to preform calculations on them.  Each of the items have certain weights and values and the end goal is to minimize the cost of combining a set number of items. When items are combined, order matters.

Say there are three items. There is a left and right slot that items can be placed in. It matters if the items are combined with one item being in a different slot. I am looking for help in finding all the possible ways the number of items can be combined. So the direction of combining two items matters as well as the order of combining the items.

Examples:

a,b
can be combined as

1. a->b
2. b->a

a,b,c
can be combined as

1. a->b --> c
2. c --> a->b
3. a->c --> b
4. b --> a->c
5. b->a --> c
6. c --> b->a
7. b->c --> a
8. a --> b->c
9. c->b --> a
10. a --> c->b
11. c->a --> b
12. b --> c->a

The shorter arrows mark which one gets combined first with the longer specifying to be combined after the first two items are combined. I did not do by hand with 4 items and onwards. The "direction" of combining the two items ie. b--> c->a vs c->a --> b is what I am really finding a hard time to put into code.

Does this remind anyone of a mathematical relationship or algorithm that has been used before? I am using java, I have tried permutations and combining it in the order of the permutation but it doesn't take into account the "direction" of combining two items.

Comment: Is this specifically for three items? Or could you have more items than that?

Comment: @templatetypedef This is for any amount of items, minimum 2. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially enumerating all ways of fusing two different structures. First, you need to enumerate all possible orderings of the n items, which is a permutations problem. This one is fairly well-studied and there are many nice recursive algorithms you can use for it.

Then, you need to enumerate all ways of grouping the permutation terms together, which boils down to enumerating all possible ways of parenthesizing an expression with n-1 terms in it (that’s the number of overall arrows applied). There are several ways to do this, and a nice recursive one is the following:

- The empty string of balanced parentheses is the only way to make a string of 0 balanced parentheses.
- Otherwise, any sequence of n balanced parentheses takes the form (P1)P2, where P1 and P2 are series of balanced parentheses. To form all options, count up from k = 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 and form all possible P1’s using k balanced parentheses and all possible P2’s using n-k-1 balanced parentheses.

Hope this helps!